# Is or was "too young for to marry" valid English, now or in the past?

Tags: british-english, old-english, middle-english

I made a very serious effort to locate the name of this song, and to find more info on it. Sadly, I was unable to. All I have is this YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWTF6nRqNvU

It appears to be a folk song from the 1500s from England, or something like that. The point is, some of the lyrics go:

> Well, sixteen years old, that's too young **for to marry**.

"For to marry"? Was this ever "valid"/common English? Is it still? I'd expect "to get married", but even in "old-timey" English terms, this sounds odd to me.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20to The usage was valid in the past but is not standard English now. _Marry_ can be used intransitively in the sense _get married_.

Comment: The song is called *Monday Morning* as on the link given by OP.

Comment: ...the [Peter, Paul & Mary version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ydv3dbNNWRs) recorded in 1965 also has that title.

Comment: Same structure in Sting's 'Fields of Gold' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AM4nWq6mU9k => ... for to gaze..."

Comment: Also at https://www.metrolyrics.com/monday-morning-lyrics-peter-paul-mary.html

Comment: 'For I want for to go to Widecombe Fair ....'

Comment: Related: [Why "enough for to fill" instead of "enough to fill" in this senetence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/why-enough-for-to-fill-instead-of-enough-to-fill-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

"For to marry"? Was this ever "valid"/common English?

Yes, it was. "For + substantive" still has the meaning of (1) "for the purpose of + substantive" or (2)"in order + to infinitive".

However, the to-infinitive, which has the properties of a gerund, is rarely used with "for" in this sense.

"We can use the iron bar for lifting it." or "We can use the iron bar in order to lift it."  (Old version "for to lift it.")

[Yale Grammatical Diversity Project English in North America](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/for-to-infinitives)

> *For to* infinitives

> "I'm goin' to Louisiana, My true love for to see." - Oh! Susanna, by Stephen Foster
>
> *For to* infinitives are verbs introduced by *for to* where Standard English would use *to,* as in (1) (Henry 1995):
>
> 1. I want **for to** meet them.

> In Standard English, it is common to introduce a clause containing an infinitive with *for* if the verb has a subject, as in (2), where *Alex* comes between *for* and *to:*
>
> 2. I want **for Alex to** meet them.

> The non-standard for to construction usually refers to sentences where there is no intervening subject, like (1).

**Edit to add:**

There is an interesting paper on the history of "for to verb" at [http://www.public.asu.edu/~gelderen/forto.htm](http://www.public.asu.edu/%7Egelderen/forto.htm)

> 

Comment: I suspect that in some of the later recorded instances, absent pretensions to folk idiom, the extra syllable may have been wanted for meter (as when "expletives their feeble aids *do* join," as Pope put it): e.g., "And are you going a ticket for to buy?" in Gilbert & Sullivan's comic opera *Patience* (1881).